# How to avoid repeating std::forward for the same variable

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have this template function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(T &&t) {
    std::forward<T>(t).foo();
    std::forward<T>(t).bar();
    std::forward<T>(t).baz();

}
```

Notice that I had to repeat `std::forward` multiple times for the same variable (to make sure that if `T` has ref-qualified `foo()`/`bar()`/`baz()`, the correct one will be called).

Is there a way to avoid repeating `std::forward`? It is not just redundant, but error-prone as well because I may forget to add `std::forward` somewhere.

Comment: After the first `std::forward<T>(t)`, you should also assume that `t` is in an unspecified state, no?

Comment: @DrewDormann: I'm not sure about that. Does a &&-qualified function surely mean that it will move the contents? It just means that the function is called on a xvalue object. It won't do the move itself (I don't call any move ctor/assignment in my example). But maybe I have the wrong idea of &&-qualified functions.

Comment: A &&-qualified function does not guarantee that contents will be moved.  Instead, it tells the compiler that you don't care whether contents are moved.  You are stating that you are no longer relying on the contents of this variable.

Comment: &&-qualified function does not have to move the content, but it is allowed to and may do it if this improves performance. So one has to assume t is unspecified to be safe.

Comment: If the forwared xvalue has it's guts stolen, it is not subsequently usable. OTOH, if the guts aren't stolen there is no benefit to forwarding.  Just never foward or move until the last place you use it.

Comment: @DrewDormann: moved where? There is no other object involved here

Comment: *moved where?* Moved to a function parameter.

Comment: @geza there is no indication how many objects are involved in the implementation of `foo()`.  If there is an rvalue implementation of `foo()`, that alone indicates that something destructive is happening, or it would not exist.  Put another way, you can not "forward" a variable and then assume that you still have the variable - you are forwarding it _somewhere_.

Comment: @DrewDormann: well, OK, maybe this question in this general form doesn't make too much sense then. For example, if `t` is a functor (like it's the comparison function in a sort), I shouldn't call `forward` on it at all (not even at the last call), because it doesn't make too much sense that a functor's operator() is ref-qualified.

Comment: @geza one could speculate that if the three calls to `std::forward` in your function are necessary and behave correctly, then the functions `foo()`, `bar()`, and `baz()` are poorly and deceptively designed.

Comment: @DrewDormann: sure. They are not necessary. This is the first time I use ref-qualified functions, I didn't think it through what they exactly mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Notice that I had to repeat std::forward multiple times for the same
> variable (to make sure that if T has ref-qualified foo()/bar()/baz(),
> the correct one will be called).

You should *not* repeat `std::forward` - you should only use it with the last call:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T &&t) {
    t.foo();
    t.bar();
    std::forward<T>(t).baz();

}
```

The way you wrote it, if the actual argument is rvalue, ref-qualified `foo()` may steal contents of `t`, and subsequent calls will not work as intended.

Comment: So the last forward is there to leave 't' in an unspecified state (so it is actually 'moved from' from the view of the caller)?

Comment: @PepijnKramer `t` will be in an unspecified state if the actual argument is rvalue. The purpose is to allow using the optimized ref-qualified version of `baz` if it exists.